# move unallocated space between partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have my Linux partition in one partition and my `/home` in another. Because a new database ended up in my Linux partition, I need more space there. Thus I took 10GB out of my `/home` partition and want to add it to my root.

According to [GParted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions), step 6, I should select sda2 and resize it. When I select sda2 there is no resize option. In short, I can't get my unallocated 10 GB into the root.

Here is a screenshot of the situation:

[image]

I am aware that the actual resize can actually be done only under boot from a live USB, while presently I am running with the disk in use.

I did get the unallocated space.

The question is how to get it to be part of `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: Once booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, all you needed to do is to issue a `swapoff` against sda5 and then resize the left side of sda2, and resize sda1, and `swapon` sda5. On a different note, your / and your swap are too small. Best to resize those when you can. Did you edit /etc/fstab with the new UUID for swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the location of the `linux-swap` partition holds you from performing the resize.

I suggest trying the following:

1. Delete the linux-swap partition
2. Resize
3. Add linux-swap partition

Comment: Thanks. You were dead on target. It was the linux-swap which was killing me. Your answer was simple and to the point.

Comment: @Ilan - Happy that it helped you! :) I had the same problem in the past, took me a while to figure out that the `linux-swap` partition cause the problem.

Comment: Once booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, all you needed to do is to issue a `swapoff` against sda5 and then resize the left side of sda2, and resize sda1, and `swapon` sda5. On a different note, your / and your swap are too small. Best to resize those when you can. Did you edit /etc/fstab with the new UUID for swap?

Comment: I suspect you are perfectly correct. What I did, in fact, was to do the swapoff, delete the swap, resize, and then add it. The crucial point was the swap was blocking the resize capability. I have 12GB of RAM so the swap never gets used.

Answer (score 0):

any partition manipulation should be done with the drive unmounted.

boot from a live cd or usb drive. be sure the live session isn't using the swap partition.

shrink the extended partition by moving where is begins to align with sda6.
then grow sda1 to use the free space.